# Rails: belongs_to association not returning the correct object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, sti

I've got an Order model with two belongs_to associations, each to a different sub-class of my Account model.  After loading an order from the database, both associations point to the same model, even though the foreign keys are correct.

```
class Account < AR::Base
end

class FooAccount < Account
end

class BarAccount < Account
end

class Order < AR::Base
  belongs_to :account, :class_name => 'FooAccount', 
    :foreign_key => :account_id
  belongs_to :different_account, :class_name => 'BarAccount', 
    :foreign_key => :different_account_id
end
```

Console does something like this:

```
o = Order.find(42)
=> #<Order id: 42, account_id: 11, different_account_id: 99>
a = Account.find(11)
=> #<FooAccount id: 11, type: "FooAccount">
d = Account.id(99)
=> #<BarAccount id: 99, type: "BarAccount">
o.account_id
=> 11
o.account
=> #<BarAccount id: 99, type: "BarAccount">
o.different_account_id
=> 99
o.different_account
=> #<BarAccount id: 99, type: "BarAccount">
```

The foreign key values are correct, but the object referenced by the association is not!  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd try and specify `foreign_key` and `class_name` for `account` too.

Comment: Do you have a method in `Order` called `account` that is overriding the `belongs_to` definition. If you remove the `belongs_to :account`, will `order.account` still point to a `BarAccount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have collisions with other methods!  I left out a definition in the Order model:

```
class Order < AR::Base
  belongs_to :account

  # a lot and a lot of code

  def account
    # does a different lookup than the association above
  end
end
```

Deleting the account method gave me the correct behavior.